# Can anyone help me with R code for the two-step generalized method of moments (GMM)

Tags: r, generalized-moments

I am new to R and need to do a 2 step Generalized Method of Moments estimation. Can anyone help me with an example code.

Thanking you.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `pgmm` in the `plm` package.

If `b` is bank capital buffer, try (slightly adapted from the vignette of the package)

```
emp.gmm <- pgmm(b~lag(b,1:2)|lag(b,2:99), data=YourData, effect="twoways", 
                model="twosteps")
summary(emp.gmm)
```

Here, the first part before `|` specifies a possible version of (you provide too little detail in that respect) the dynamic panel estimating equation, and after, you specify the GMM instruments. The further options yields the AB estimator and are explained more fully in the vignette.

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality, because it is so short. In truth, it is more of a comment than an answer by CV's standards. Can you expand on this? Why / how will `pgmm` resolve the OP's issue, eg?

Comment: You are certainly right that this is pretty short for an answer, but I felt that in this particular case, it actually *is* the answer. I will edit a little, but feel free to delete or repost as a comment.

Comment: You're right. Really, this Q is off topic here & should be closed. Nonetheless, this is an improvement. Thanks.